# Java Update Micrometer Gauge with Dynamic Labels

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm using Java Micrometer gauge to measure a metric that has a range of labels. The label values are dynamically retrieved but bounded.

For example: I have `withdraw.cycle` metric with label `currency`.

Because Micrometer doesn't hold the reference to the gauge itself, it makes the code look quite cumbersome.

I've got two ways to do it:

```
private void updateGauge(String currency, int minutes) {
    Tags tags = Tags.of("currency", currency);
    Gauge.builder("withdraw.cycle",() -> minutes)
         .tags(tags)
         .strongReference(true)
         .register(meterRegistry);
}
```

**OR**

```
private final Map<Tags, AtomicLong> cycleGaugeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// Use cycleGaugeMap to hold the reference to the gauge
private void updateGauge(String currency, int minutes) {
    Tags tags = Tags.of("currency", currency);
    if (cycleGaugeMap.containsKey(tags)) {
        cycleGaugeMap.get(tags).set(minutes);
    } else {
        AtomicLong old = cycleGaugeMap.putIfAbsent(tags, meterRegistry.gauge("withdraw.cycle", tags,
                                                                                     new AtomicLong(minutes)));
        if (old != null) {
            old.set(minutes);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Question:** Are they the right ways to do it or does Micrometer have an API that I'm not aware of for such cases? I'd really want to know a "standard" and elegant way to do it.

Comment: Does your app use spring-boot?

Comment: @AnishB. Yes, it's a spring boot app.

Comment: I would say the first option since Micrometer has a Map of all the Meters. The register method will either create a new Gauge or return an existing one if the combination of the name and tags already was used.
(see the JavaDoc on the register method for more details)

Instead of using the Gauge builder directly, you can use the gauge method on the registry

Example:
meterRegistry.gauge("withdraw.cycle", 
    Tags.of("currency", currency),
    minutes);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly follow this github issue [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/3826).

**To Summarize:**

- First approach to update gauge is via [MultiGauge](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_multi_gauge):

> By definition, Micrometer supports one special type of Gauge, called a
> `MultiGauge`, to help manage gauging a growing or shrinking list of
> criteria. This feature lets you select a set of well-bounded but
> slightly changing set of criteria from something like an SQL query and
> report some metric for each row as a Gauge.

Working example:

```
public class Example {

    private static final SimpleMeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
    private static final MultiGauge gauge = MultiGauge.builder("withdraw.cycle").register(registry);

    private static final Map<String, Number> values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 

    private static void updateGauge(String currency, int minutes) {
        values.put(currency, minutes);
        List<MultiGauge.Row<?>> rows = values.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(row -> MultiGauge.Row.of(Tags.of("currency", row.getKey()), row.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        gauge.register(rows, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       updateGauge("Rupee", 1);
       System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
       System.out.println("--------");
       updateGauge("Dollar", 2);
       System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
       System.out.println("--------");
       updateGauge("Rupee", 3);
       System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
    }
```

Output:

```
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Rupee']; value=1.0
--------
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Dollar']; value=2.0
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Rupee']; value=1.0
--------
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Dollar']; value=2.0
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Rupee']; value=3.0
```

- Second Approach to update gauge via `Gauge` itself.

Working example:

```
public class Example {

    private static final SimpleMeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();

    private static final Map<String, Number> values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private static void updateGauge(String currency, int minutes) {
        Tags tags = Tags.of("currency", currency);
        values.put(currency, minutes);
        if (registry.find("withdraw.cycle").tags(tags).gauge() == null) {
            Gauge.builder("withdraw.cycle", () -> values.get(currency))
                    .tags(tags)
                    .register(registry);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        updateGauge("Rupee", 1);
        System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
        System.out.println("--------");
        updateGauge("Dollar", 2);
        System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
        System.out.println("--------");
        updateGauge("Rupee", 3);
        System.out.println(registry.getMetersAsString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Rupee']; value=1.0
--------
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Dollar']; value=2.0
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Rupee']; value=1.0
--------
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Dollar']; value=2.0
withdraw.cycle(GAUGE)[currency='Rupee']; value=3.0
```

I guess this is the optimal approach that you were looking for.

Comment: I tried MultiGauge, but it doesn't work this way. The gauge with newer tags would just overwrite the previous ones. If you change to second `updateGauge` to `updateGauge("Dollar", 2);`, only the gauge with tag `Dollar` exists.  The `Rupee` one is overwritten.

Comment: The second approach seems to work well and it's quite elegant.

Comment: @JFreebird Multigauge way should have worked too. Let me check on that.

Comment: @JFreebird I have updated my answer and fixed the MultiGauge part. Also, update the example with multiple use cases. Please verify now. Everything works. :)

Comment: @JFreebird I guess the MultiGauge approach is quite cleaner way than the normal way. But you can choose as per your wish.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about micrometer not storing the reference to a gauge, so your second approach looks correct and in order with what is mentioned in micrometer [documentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauges):

```java
// maintain a reference to myGauge
AtomicInteger myGauge = registry.gauge("numberGauge", new AtomicInteger(0));

// ... elsewhere you can update the value it holds using the object reference
myGauge.set(27);
myGauge.set(11);
```

I would, however, change that code a bit, as it has come race conditions:

```java
  private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> cycleGaugeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  // Use cycleGaugeMap to hold the reference to the gauge
  private void updateGauge(String currency, int minutes) {
    cycleGaugeMap.compute(currency, (k, v) -> {
      if (v == null) {
        v = meterRegistry.gauge("withdraw.cycle", Tags.of("currency", currency), new AtomicLong(minutes));
      } else {
        v.set(minutes);
      }
      return v;
    });
  }
```

Comment: How about the first one?  Keeping a reference in my own code is not the cleanest way.  I'll need multiple maps if I have more gauge metrics.

Comment: @JFreebird that won't work. You can check using the following code sample:
```
    SimpleMeterRegistry meterRegistry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
    Tags tags = Tags.of("currency", "a");
    Gauge.builder("withdraw.cycle",() -> 10)
      .tags(tags)
      .strongReference(true)
      .register(meterRegistry);
    System.out.println(meterRegistry.getMetersAsString());
    Gauge.builder("withdraw.cycle",() -> 20)
      .tags(tags)
      .strongReference(true)
      .register(meterRegistry);
    System.out.println(meterRegistry.getMetersAsString());
```
It would print "...10.0"

Comment: @JFreebird and the reason is `register` won't create a new gauge if one already exists with that combination of tags (and other properties). And it won't reassign a supplier for an existing gouge.

Comment: I think Anish B's second example seems to be simpler. It doesn't require map computations. The gauge can directly get values from the map, and I can just use Integer/Long classes etc. as map entries instead of the Atomic classes.

Answer (score -1):

Micrometer doesn't provide a direct API for updating the value of a gauge with dynamically retrieved labels, so your approaches are reasonable workarounds. However, your second approach using a `ConcurrentHashMap` to hold references to the gauges can be improved for clarity and safety. Here's an updated version of your second approach:

```java
private final ConcurrentMap<Tags, AtomicLong> cycleGaugeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void updateGauge(String currency, int minutes) {
    Tags tags = Tags.of("currency", currency);
    AtomicLong gaugeValue = cycleGaugeMap.computeIfAbsent(tags, key -> {
        AtomicLong gauge = new AtomicLong(minutes);
        meterRegistry.gauge("withdraw.cycle", tags, gauge);
        return gauge;
    });

    gaugeValue.set(minutes);
}
```

In this updated version, `computeIfAbsent` is used to atomically check if the gauge already exists in the `cycleGaugeMap`. If it doesn't exist, it creates the gauge and registers it with Micrometer before returning the reference to it. This ensures that gauge creation and retrieval are done atomically and avoids the need to separately check and putIfAbsent.

This approach is more concise and still thread-safe. It also clearly conveys your intention of creating and managing gauges dynamically while keeping track of them for future updates.

Overall, this updated version of your second approach is a reasonable and elegant way to manage dynamically labeled gauges in Micrometer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think Anish B's second example seems to be cleaner. It doesn't require map computations.  The gauge can directly get value from the map, and I can just use Integer/Long etc. as map entries instead of Atomic classes.